# Memory loss when passed as an argument to a class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, visual-c++, arguments

I defined a class with a template that defines a generic array type T number of elements N. I have another class that has an instance of this array as a member. When I try using the setString function, the array I pass goes from 15 elements, to 4 elements, arbitrarily.

```
// testClassArraySize.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T, int N>
class CArray {
public:
    T arr[N];
    CArray(void) {/*arr=(T *)malloc(sizeof(T)*N);*/
        if (arr == NULL) {
            cout << "allocation error\n";
        }
    }
    ;
    //CArray (int n) {arr=new T [n]; if(arr==NULL){exit(0); cout<<"allocation error\n";}};
    CArray operator=(const T *);
    T operator[](const int i) {
        return arr[i];
    }
    ;
};

template<class T, int N>
CArray<T, N> CArray<T, N>::operator=(const T *srce) {
    size_t x = sizeof(arr);
    size_t y = sizeof(srce);
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(arr); j++) {
        if (j > sizeof(srce)) {
            arr[j] = 0;
            break;
        }
        arr[j] = srce[j];
    }
    return *this;
}

class myTestClass {
private:
    CArray<char, 15> myString;
public:
    myTestClass setString(char set[15]) {
        myString = set;
        size_t x = sizeof(set);
        return *this;
    }
    ;
};

int main() {
    myTestClass myObject;
    myObject.setString("helloWorld");
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Surely you haven't enabled any compiler warnings, have you? Those can be very helpful.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but on MSVC10 there aren't any. Where would you expect one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has a couple of issues, but the one you'll probably see is the line

```
CArray<T, N> CArray<T, N>::operator= (const T *srce)
```

Note: `const T* source` is a pointer, therefore `sizeof(srce)` is the size of the pointer. I guess you're using a 32 bit system?

`sizeof` gives you the size of an object (i.e. a "region of storage"). For arrays, that is the size of the whole array in bytes. `sizeof( int[10] ) == sizeof(int) * 10`. A pointer is itself an object, with a size depending on the C++ implementation (OS, compiler and so on). On 32 bit systems, it typically is 4 byte. `sizeof( char* )` therefore is 4 byte, not the length of the array you passed to the function, that is `sizeof( (char*)(char[10]) )` still is 4 byte, not 10.

Another issue you may see (but only by debugging / tracing) is that `setString(char set[15])` is resolved to `setString(char* set)`. Therefore `x = sizeof(set)` resolves to `x = sizeof(char*)` which is typically 4.

You pass "helloWorld" to `setString`, which is expecting a <strike>15-item char array</strike>`char*`; I would say this is not a good idea since "helloWorld" has type `char const[10]` (note the `const`).
The correct syntax for taking a 15-char array is `char (&set)[15]`.

You can do this more elegantly if you add a template member function like:

```
// in class CArray
template < std::size_t length >
CArray& operator= (const T (&srce)[length]);    // note I return a reference, so no copying
```

This way, you'll get the array size as a template argument. Note: since I used `const T` here in the assignment op, you'll need to enforce const also in `setString`.

```
template < class T, int N >
template < std::size_t srce_length >
CArray < T, N >& CArray < T, N > :: operator= (const T (&srce)[srce_length])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {    // N is the own length
        if (j >= srce_length) {    // note the >= instead of >, and srce_length instead of sizeof
            arr[j] = 0;
            break;
        }
        arr[j] = srce[j];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I pass the array to setString, before I even call CArray operator= (const T *srce), the memory is still lost... Ill try this solution however.

Comment: Try changing the signature of `setString` to `char const (&set)[15]` as I mentioned.

Comment: okay, Thank you. This helps. I don't understand what putting the address operator as a parameter or return value does however.

Comment: In both cases, it declares a reference. References can be seen as "just another name for an existing object". If you leave out the reference on the return value, you'll (semantically) return a _copy_.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it worked. I actually added the template to both. Just one more question: If I ended up having a different size of the source in the first place every time I called the function, doesn't the compiler create a different function with the different sizes? My understanding was that templates create identical functions with the various special cases every time they are called with different template arguments.

Comment: This is true, it's called "template instantiation", and _can_ lead to something called code bloat (that is, a lot of similar code created by using templates). But when the function is small, the compiler may also _inline_ it, that is, it could just replace the function call with the code/implementation of the function. There are techniques to avoid code bloat, but I think you should consider them only when you found out that you _do_ have a problem in your specific case (e.g. too large executionable).